# How to check iPhone network type GSM or CDMA

Tags: iphone, gsm, cdma

In my application I need to check network type GSM or CDMA (for Verizon). I found CTCarrier class which contains property mobileNetworkCode, but I don't wanna hardcode value for each providers. Are there other ways to check it?

Please help.

Comment: You make me curious, why do you need this information?

Comment: I have specific server side logic, also I need it for statistic.

Comment: If CoreTelephony.framework doesn't provide such an API, I doubt if there's an AppStore-compatible way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You could get that through the Model#, but then again, you have to hardcode a list of Model# and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do that by checking the IP Address of the iPhone if it is wireless connected. If once detected it would´t change unless you change the SIM ;-)

At http://www.tcpiputils.com/browse/ip-address/192.76.85.245 you get information on verizon IP space