# Is it possible to determine the network type (GSM/CDMA)?

Tags: ios

Is it possible to determine the network type - GSM or CDMA?

I had a look at Core Telephony but didn't see anything, it seems its possible to find out the carrier and infer it from that, but I'd prefer to get the type itself directly if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check iPhone network type GSM or CDMA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041508/how-to-check-iphone-network-type-gsm-or-cdma)

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596079/how-to-check-if-iphone-supports-cdma-or-gsm

Hope this helps!