# iOS To find out if the phone is CDMA or GSM

Tags: ios

We want to collect our users' phone carrier type,but I can't tell the phone is `GSM` or `CDMA` using `CTTelephonyNetworkInfo`

```
CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS     
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge         
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA        
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA        
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA        
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x       
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0 
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA 
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB 
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD        
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0); CORETELEPHONY_EXTERN NSString * const CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE          
__OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_NA,__IPHONE_7_0);
```

Comment: You can found your answer in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041508/how-to-check-iphone-network-type-gsm-or-cdma

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
NSString* machine () {
        size_t size;

            // Set 'oldp' parameter to NULL to get the size of the data
            // returned so we can allocate appropriate amount of space
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); 

            // Allocate the space to store name
        char *name = malloc(size);

            // Get the platform name
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", name, &size, NULL, 0);

            // Place name into a string
        NSString *machineid = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];

            // Done with this
        free(name);

        return machineid;
    }
```

Function will return string like @"iPhone3,3" which stands for iPhone 4 (CDMA/Verizon).